# Reference options of `read` on the command line

Tags: bash

I am learning `read` command,
there are multiple options including `-p`, `-e`, `-i`,
For instance:

```
    if read -t 10 -sp "Enter secret passphrase > " secret_pass; then
        echo -e  "\nSecret passphrase = 'secret_pass'"
    else
        echo -e  "\nInput timed out" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
```

However, I cannot locate the options from commmand line

```
    $ man read | grep -e '-e' -e '-p'
    #it return nothing.
```

Additionally I checked  BSD official and failed to find the options.
[read(2)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?read(2))

How to check them from command line?

Comment: `read` is a shell builtin. To get help for read and other builtins, type `help read` or `help cd`, etc.

Comment: You didn't identify the correct documentation page for `read` on the BSD site. The one you have found is about the system call, you are interested in the shell command. This is the correct page https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=read&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE+and+Ports but it doesn't tell much. You can find the documentation of `read` in the [`bash` documentation page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bash&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+11.1-RELEASE+and+Ports) (because it is an internal `bash` command) or by running `man bash`. It is a long documentation, be patient.

Comment: `man cd` shows its BSD builtins, `help cd` shows it's GNU bash builtin, version 4.4.19(1).When I `cd dir` in command line, whose builtin is working? @Pawamoy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `read` is a shell built-in. You can either check the manual for `Bash`

```
man bash
```

and search for `read` or you can type

```
help read
```

in a `Bash` shell.

**UPDATE**

Your follow up question from the comments:

Bash will use its builtin function first. If there is also an executable on your system, which you want to use instead, then you will have to call it by its full path, e.g.,

```
$ echo Hello # This calls Bash's version of echo
$ /usr/bin/echo World # This calls echo that was installed with the OS
```

This applies to all commands that exist as executable on the system and also have a builtin counterpart. I am not familiar with BSD but on Linux there is no `cd` executable. This would mean that a program can change Bash's working directory from outside. I do not know why BSD has such a program and if `Bash` would even allow it to change its working directory.

Comment: Could I ask `man cd` shows its BSD builtins, `help cd` shows it's GNU bash builtin, version 4.4.19(1).When I `cd dir` in command line, whose builtin is working?

Comment: @Tool I think BSD builtins are only related to its `sh` implementation (executable `sh` or `csh`). Since Bash is Bash, typing `cd` in Bash uses Bash's builtin `cd`. You can verify with `type cd`.

Answer (score 1):

> How to check them from command line?

It's easiest with nautical's suggestion `help read`, provided that your command line shell is `bash`, or `bash -c 'help read'` in case your command line shell is some other kind of shell.

If you want to read the manual section rather than the `help` text, you could use:

```
man bash | more +/'read *\['
```

> `man cd` shows its BSD builtins, `help cd` shows it's GNU bash builtin, version 4.4.19(1).When I `cd dir` in command line, whose builtin is working?

The built-in command of the used shell is executed. If unsure which shell it is, enter `echo $0`.

Comment: I tried `$ man bash | sed -n '/^ *read \[/,/^$/p'` and  ` man bash | sed -n "/^ *read \[/,/^$/p"`  , it returns blank. $ echo $0
-bash #this indicate i'm running login shell.

Comment: @Tool - I replaced my suggestion with more portable alternatives.